# Let / be a field extension. Show that complex conjugation defines an element of Aut().

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let / be a field extension. Show that complex conjugation defines an element of Aut().

I am not sure about how to show it. Isn't it intuitive from the fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Comment: What do you get with $L = \mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi /3} 2^{1/3})$ given it is isomorphic to $F = \mathbb{Q}( 2^{1/3})$ ?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}$ remains fixed under complex congjugation, also it is a homomorphism.  Is it bijective $L \rightarrow L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is not true unless the extension is normal (all extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are separable, so this is equivalent to being Galois).

**Theorem** Let $L / \mathbb{Q}$ be a algebraic galois field extension (without loss of generality, we take $L$ to be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ algebraic and galois over $\mathbb{Q}$). Then complex conjugation defines an automorphism on this field.

**Proof:** Let $\sigma$ be complex conjugation. Since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is normal (splitting field of a polynomial $f$), and since $\sigma$ sends roots of $f$ to other roots of $f$, $\sigma|_L$ image contained in $L$. Since $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic extension, it is bijective on the roots of any irreducible polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ contained in $L$, i.e. the set $S_p = \{ a \in L : p(a) = 0 \}$ for any irreducible polynomial contained in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. And element in $L$ occurs as the root of such an irreducible polynomial, as $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic.

If the extension is not normal, then we may (but not must) have a problem. Like reuns said, $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2 i \pi / 3} 2^{1/3})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$. Complex conjugation sends $e^{2 \pi i \pi / 3}$ to $e^{2 \pi i \pi (2/ 3)}$, but the second is not contained in this extension.

By the way, in general, if we replace $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{Q}$ with $M / K$, and $L$ is an intermediate field, then we shouldn't expect an $K$-automorphism $\sigma: M \rightarrow M$ to induce an automorphism of $L$ at all. Instead, we have a bunch of different intermediate fields $\{ \sigma ( L ) : \sigma \in \text{Aut}_K (M) \}$.